# Show that for any $L_1, L_2\in Lag(E,\omega)$ there exists a symplectic basis in which $L_1=<e_1,..,e_n>$ and $L_2 =<e_1,...,e_k,f_{k+1},..,f_n>$

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I'm a beginner on sympletic geometry, studiyng by the Meinrenken notes, need a help in a question.

Let $(E,\omega)$ sympletic space and $L_1, L_2\in Lag(E,\omega)$ lagrangians such that $dim(L_1\cap L_2)=k$. Show that exists a symplectic basis in which $L_1=\langle e_1,..,e_n\rangle$ and $L_2 =\langle e_1,...,e_k,f_{k+1},..,f_n\rangle$.

Need some hint to start the exercises.

Comment: Hmm... are you sure $\dim L_1=k<n=\dim L_2$?

Comment: Sorry, i'll correct, it's $dim(L_1)=n$. Thanks

Comment: *Hint*: $e_1,\dots,e_k$ are obvious.  For the others, consider $\{\omega(v,-)\vert_{L_2}: v\in L_1\}\subset L_2^\vee$.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for angle brackets, not `<` and `>`. Compare $\langle a\rangle$ and $<a>$.

Comment: @user10354138 I can't figure out how to complete with this subspace. Also, i assume that the notation $L_2^{\vee}$ is the $\omega$-orthogonal space of $L_2$.

Comment: $V^\vee$ is the dual space of $V$.

Comment: Ok. But i'm stucked in begin this question, in fact at this beggining of study SympGeo. I'll try again in a couple days.. Thanks